# How can you query and SUM total a Column name, rather than "=SUM(A:A)" in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

- I want to create a query that uses SUM to add total all values in a column,
  into a single cell, using a distinct column name.

Sometimes the Column may move when new inventory is added, causing the reference to fail/not match...

I want the reference to connect to a distinct column name, not "A:A"

*From my research, it seems the answer is along the lines of ADDRESS() and/or MATCH()*

But here's the simple [Query and Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deknu.png), referencing to column "A":

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A:A, "select sum (A) label sum (A) ''")
```

You can also see I set the label to '' so it only returned the value.

Any help or advice to help pipe the API data into a main sheet would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample sheet names and setup, delete everything from Sheet1, B2:B (i.e., all QUERY formulas). Then place the following formula into Sheet1!B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),TRANSPOSE(FILTER({Sheet2!1:1;MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet2!A2:A),1,0),INDIRECT("Sheet2!2:"&ROWS(Sheet2!A:A))*1)},Sheet2!1:1<>"")),2,FALSE),0))`

It is unclear from your post where the labels "Apple" and "Pear" in Sheet1 must stay  in the order they appear. If they *do not*, you could simplify the formula. In this case, you would delete Sheet1!A2:B (i.e., all labels and formulas) and place the following formula in Sheet1!A2:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(FILTER({Sheet2!1:1;MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet2!A2:A),1,0),INDIRECT("Sheet2!2:"&ROWS(Sheet2!A:A))*1)},Sheet2!1:1<>"")))`

Either formula will produce all of the results for all categories.

Note that both formulas have one instance of `INDIRECT`. This is to make the formulas truly dynamic, taking into account however many rows and columns you may have in Sheet2. But this also means that this one `INDIRECT` reference to `Sheet2` is no longer dynamic. So if you change the name of Sheet2 to something else, while all of the other references will automatically adjust, this one *will not*. You will need to manually change that one `INDIRECT` sheet name reference in the formula if you do change the name of Sheet2 to something else.